# Infinitely recurring edit review

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, notifications

A while ago an edit was proposed to one of my questions, reviewed and rejected by another contributor. Now every few hours the edit is being added to my inbox for my attention. I can't do anything with it, because it was already rejected, so I skip. But a few hours later it comes back again. Does anyone have any way to deal with this?

This happens with just the global inbox.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10044

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Next time it happens, could you grab a screen shot from the inbox?  I'm specifically interested in knowing whether it's a new notification (updated timestamp) or a ghost from the past (old timestamp corresponding to the original notification).  I saw (somewhere) a bug report about ghosts of notifications past, so maybe this is related.  (Or not.  We'll see.)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I will do that.